# MaskedTextBox If empty insert NULL into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, maskedtextbox

I have got this code below which care whether `maskedtextbox is empty`. If it is empty it `INSERT INTO`  SQL table `__.__.____` - only the mask so I believe it `INSERTS NULL`  But something got wrong when I fill the `maskedtextbox`. It still `INSERT` `__.__.____` - NULL  I don't know where I make mistake because it should normally insert the `date` which is in the maskedtextbox.

The mask for this textbox is `__.__.____` like `00/00/0000`

Data type in which I insert this data is  - date.

Here is the code:

```
var value2 = (object)DBNull.Value;
DateTime parsedDate2;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(maskedTextBox2.Text, "__.__.____", null,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate2))
{
    value2 = parsedDate2;
}
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjdate", value2);
```

Edit : This code below says: the name 'value2' does not exist in the current context'

```
var value2 = (object)DBNull.Value;
DateTime parsedDate2;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(maskedTextBox2.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate2))
{
    value2 = parsedDate2;
}
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjdate", value2);
```

This code below does this Ex:

```
Converting into data type date wasn't succesfull.
```

This is the code

```
if (maskedTextBox2.Text == "__.__.____")
{
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjdate", null);
}
else
{
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjdate",maskedTextBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: You have to give the format in `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of `__...` what is your mask format?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you for your comment, my mask is 00/00/0000 - / is replaced with .

Comment: How does your `maskedTextBox2.Text` value looks like? show sample

Comment: 12.12.2012 This is example

Comment: MM.dd.yyyy or dd.MM.yyyy ?

Comment: Im not sure :( In SQL database it is like 2012-12-12, but I insert it like 12.12.2012 - dd.MM.yyyy atleast I hope first is day then is month and year is in the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34849/discussion-between-marek-and-sriram-sakthivel)

Comment: @Marek by default, your `maskedTextBox.Text` will be like as what you can see but if you modify the `MaskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat` such as `maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;`, it will be different, for example, `12.12.2012` will be `12122012` and it could be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
 var value2 = (Object)DBNull.Value;
 DateTime parsedDate2;
 if (DateTime.TryParse(maskedTextBox1 .Text, out parsedDate2))
 {
   value2 = (Object)parsedDate2;
 }
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjdate", value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var value2 = (object)DBNull.Value;
DateTime parsedDate2;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(maskedTextBox2.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate2))
{
    value2 = parsedDate2;
}
```

Note: if your format is "MM.dd.yyyy" then replace format to make the parse to work!

This should work

Comment: I edited my answer it give sme this error - The name 'value2' does not exist in the current context , I edited answer so you can see what I entered.

Comment: @Marek You didn't delete the line that says `var value2 = ...`, did you?

Comment: No i just given OP the portion to replace. I haven't suggested to delete any other lines. Is it clear now @Marek

Comment: @jszigeti Op would have deleted `var value2 = ..`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you it was my mistake, I deleted var value.. But it still inserts NULL if the maskedtextbox is filled :/

Comment: you mean if maskedtextbox  is not filled?

Comment: No, if I fill it, it inserts NULL :(

Comment: you filled valid value or what? `dd` should be less than or equal to `31`, `MM` <= `12` ?

Comment: I filled 12.12.2012 but in database I get null value. Dont you know where I make mistake?

Comment: Put a break point and check what value you're passing to sql. If correct value is passed probably issue will be in `StoredProcedure` if you're using SP

Comment: @Marek I'd actually put a breakpoint inside the if statement to see if the TryParseExact is correctly identifying your string (this can also check if your masked text box is working)

Comment: @Marek As jszigeti told try to put breakpoint and see whether it is getting inside If or not.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That is exactly what I have done, but it says that value2 is null, but I'm not sure exactly why :/

Comment: Whether it went inside If?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, exactly there.

Comment: If it went inside `IF` definitely value2 will have a value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34850/discussion-between-marek-and-sriram-sakthivel)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it says that value2 is null inside IF Im not sure why

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the parseddate2 is like 1. 1. 0001 isnt it because of that?